# How can I create keyboard interrupts to provide a signal to a code in c in windows?

Tags: c, string, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt, isr

How can I create keyboard interrupts to provide a signal to a code in c in windows(like to start printing the string in reverse direction)? Materials regarding this would be helpful too! helpful too!
I do not have prior knowledge of creating interrupts.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? If the code has nothing else to do, it can just call `getchar()` for a key input. Or in Windows, `getch()`.

Comment: the situation is like whenever I press enter I want the string to be printed in reverse